# Node js, Javascript : why funtion return value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have no idea about this problem. I try to find something, but still have no idea..
this is my code

```
function part1(sql, controltime, headers_view, results_view, tmp){
    var timerName = "QueryTime";
    var request = new Request(sql, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more, rows) {
        if(!more){
            console.timeEnd(timerName);
        }
    });
    var result = "";
    var header = "";
    request.on('row', function(columns) { 
        headers_view = '\n'
        results_view += '\n'
        columns.forEach(function(column) {          
            if (column.value === null) {  
                result = '0';
            } else {
                    header = column.metadata.colName;
                    result = column.value;
            }
            headers_view += header + ',';
            results_view += result + ',';
            
        }); 
        headers_view = headers_view.replace(',\n','\n').slice(0,-1);
        results_view = results_view.replace(',\n','\n').slice(0,-1);

        tmp = controltime;

    }); 
    console.log(request)
    return {headers_view:headers_view, results_view:results_view, tmp:tmp, request:request};
}
```

above console.log(request) results is

```
Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { doneProc: [Function], row: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  sqlTextOrProcedure: " SELECT [Head],round([Avg],2) as 'Class_Top' FROM [Class1].[dbo].[Class1_Control] WHERE DateTime='2020-07-26 12:30:32' ",
  parameters: [],
  parametersByName: {},
  originalParameters: [],
  preparing: false,
  canceled: false,
  paused: false,
  userCallback: [Function],
  handle: undefined,
  error: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  rows: undefined,
  rst: undefined,
  rowCount: undefined,
  callback: [Function],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

this result is what i want. but the problem is

```
async function exec1(sql, controltime) {
    part1(sql, controltime, headers_view1, results_view1, tmp1);
    var headers_view1 = part1.headers_view;
    var results_view1 = part1.results_view;
    var tmp1 = part1.tmp;
    var request = part1.request;
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log(part1.request);
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log('====================================')
    console.log(request)
    console.log('====================================')
    //console.time(timerName);
    const query = await Promise.all([
        dbconn1.execSql(request)
    ]);
}
```

above both console.log(request) & (part1.request) are undefined
So, I try to change async -> sync

```
function exec1(sql, controltime) {
    part1(sql, controltime, headers_view1, results_view1, tmp1);
    var headers_view1 = part1.headers_view;
    var results_view1 = part1.results_view;
    var tmp1 = part1.tmp;
    var request = part1.request;
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log(part1.request);
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log('====================================')
    console.log(request)
    console.log('====================================')
    //console.time(timerName);
    dbconn1.execSql(request)

}
```

but still undefined...
someone told me try to use success/failure method
The question is

1. if i try to use success/failure method, is it right insert into part1?
2. if i try to change async -> sync, why both results are undefined?
3. how can i transmit right request value?

Thank you for read this long question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part1 is a function, but you are trying to log the return value.

On your first line you have to store the return value of part1 in something, then later log something.request.

So first line should be something like

var something = part1(sql, controltime, headers_view1, results_view1, tmp1);

then

console.log (something.request)